Should a word beginning a quotation be capitalized?
I've googled this and cannot find the answer anywhere.

My mom told me to "Sit down and be quiet or else I'll pancake you."
My mom told me to "sit down and be quiet or else I'll pancake you."

I want to use quotes here for a personal reason, but should sit be capitalized or not?

https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/citations/quotations

@Stuart I can't find a duplicate; the APA guidelines give a clear example not capitalising. I'd give it as an answer (perhaps with a reference from another style guide). // But here, I'd say the structure is infelicitous. << My mom told me to "sit down and be quiet" >> works as a report structure containing a quote, as does the quote structure << My mom said curtly to me "Sit down and be quiet or else I'll pancake you." >> //// If you don't answer, I'll convert this to one.

If you'd like to ask "Must a direct quote embedded in a sentence be capitalized," the answer is absolutely not.

The following [re-ordered and annotated] is stated by Purdue Online Writing Lab.
The first two situations address quotes in quotative structures ('direct speech', spoken or taken verbatim from a book, article, notice etc. It becomes tricky when it is important to faithfully show that an actual quote from a written source begins with a lower-case letter):

... 2. Do not use a capital letter when the quoted material is a
fragment or a piece of the original sentence.

Mr. Johnson, who was working in his field that morning, said, "The alien spaceship appeared right before my own two eyes."

... 4. If a direct quotation is interrupted mid-sentence, do not
capitalize the second part of the quotation.

"I didn't see an actual alien being," Mr. Johnson said, "but I sure wish I had."


The other situation needing addressing is when the quote is not a full sentence, and appears in a report structure ('indirect speech, with a reporting verb + complementiser that/whether/if or a catenation ['told/asked/ordered ... me to ...']):

... 3. Do not use a capital letter when the quoted material is a
fragment or only a piece of the original material's complete sentence.

Although Mr. Johnson has seen odd happenings on the farm, he stated that the spaceship "certainly takes the cake" when it comes to
unexplainable activity.


APA Style Guide (mentioned by Stuart F) gives the same advice not to capitalise, even for reasonably short partial quotes that are complete sentences:

For quotations of fewer than 40 words, add quotation marks around the
words and incorporate the quote into your own text — there is no
additional formatting needed.

Effective teams can be difficult to describe because “high performance along one domain does not translate to high performance
along another” (Ervin et al., 2018, p. 470).)


......................
But note the caveat incorporate the quote into your own text.
While the quotative structure

My mom told me: "Sit down and be quiet or else I'll pancake you."

using 'tell' as a quotative verb is correct,

My mom told me to "S/sit down and be quiet or else I'll pancake you."

is ungrammatical.

My mom told me to "sit down and be quiet."

does work, however.

I find the grammar of quotations relatively baffling, but I'm pretty sure your third bullet item is missing a quote.

Thanks: and the capital s was suboptimal.

I believe most style guides would prescribe no capital in this situation. My style guide of choice—The Chicago Manual of Style—says:

12.19: Initial capital or lowercase—run-in quotations
When a quotation introduced mid-sentence forms a syntactical part of the
sentence . . . , it begins with a lowercase letter even if the original
begins with a capital.
[selected example]
Benjamin Franklin admonishes us to
“plough deep while sluggards sleep.”
Source: The
Chicago Manual of Style:
12.19 (login required)

So:

My mom told me to “sit down and be quiet or else I’ll pancake you.”

There are exceptions, which I won’t risk overquoting here. But dialog style, of course, requires a different treatment:

My mom told me, “Sit down and be quiet or else I’ll pancake you.”


I'm not happy that the scope of 'to' seems to be infelicitously extended beyond the imperative << sit down and be quiet >> in  OP.
